# How does a +physical damage gem affect my weapon's DPS?

Tags: torchlight-2

Will the + physical damage apply only to regular attacks, or also to spells and skills? If so, which ones?

Will it modify my weapon's DPS? That is, I realize it would do more damage, but some skills like Venomous Hail do damaged based on the weapon's DPS, e.g. 50% of weapon DPS for each of 8 shots. If I add a +54 physical damage gem to the weapon, will the damage of venomous hail increase as well, or will it not because the weapon's DPS is technically unchanged?

The same question applies to gems that increase weapon attack speed.

Answer (score 2):

I applied the +54 physical damage gem to my weapon socket. The listed DPS in the Arcane Statistics screen did indeed go up. Because it was a fast weapon, it went up a lot. On a test dummy, the skills appear to do much more damage now than they did before.

As to weapon speed, it seems the same applies. The outlander charge gives +% attack speed, which increases the listed DPS, and leads to an increase in skill damage.